# Syncing two computers with unison and ssh

Tags: synchronization, unison

I have two machines, one is a laptop and the other is a desktop computer located in my room at the university behind a firewall.

Is there a way I can use `unison` to synchronize folders between these two machine? I can do this by mounting the remote file system localy but I was hoping for something more elegant.

**Edit:**
When I'm tyring to sync localy to a mounter folder I get an error:

> Operation not permitted

I can write to the folder directly (e.g. creating a file and saving it with emacs)

Comment: What kind of access do you have between the two machines? Unison works over ssh, so I assume you don't have a direct ssh connection. If you only have a machine that you can reach from both, you can establish a reverse ssh tunnel. But if you can mount one machine's filesystem from the other, the natural way is to use unison locally!

Comment: @Gilles:  have an ssh connection established between the two machines. I tried to do the reverese ssh trick but it didn't work (probably beacouse I didn't understand it, or I don't have sufficient permissions on the server). Currently I'm doing this locally but I still get an error. I'll update my question.

Comment: How exactly did you configure unison? Post your profile file, and the output of `ls -ld` on the two root directories.

Answer (score 1):

If you have SSH access to your laptop, then you can run unison on your desktop machine behind firewall and sync through an SSH connectin.

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps use ssh with tunnelling feature and (assuming that your laptop is on internet with public ipaddress).

Comment: I have set a connection to the  remote machine (the desktop) to go throuh the gateway using my hosts file and proxycommand. When I try to connect (in the GUI interface) I get an error: ``Lost connection with the server``